# Storing password to use later

Tags: authentication, passwords, web-application, api

I have a deployment system with a user interface that is accessible over the Internet. I want to make it more secure by re rolling the password periodically over the API. Is there a safe way I can store the password locally on my computer? I’m worried about someone brute forcing the password on the publicly available interface.

Comment: Using the _change password_ form?

Comment: I’m going to do it directly over the REST API.

Comment: Ok, _using the change password REST API_. But, could you clarify where's the problem?

Comment: I want to access the password. I want to automate the whole process so I need to store the password for later use. I can’t hash it because I need to use it for an environment variable in a service.

Comment: Is your computer presumed secure? It will depend on your threat model. If you are only worried about the publicly available interface, storage in local computer should be no issue.

Comment: Is there a best way to encrypt the password? I’d prefer not saving it in plain text. Ideally, I could use a password only I know as a key so I can re roll the public password automatically without exposing my private password to brute force. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're the system's developer, that's an insecure model. The password should be salted and hashed at client side, then hashed again with a server-supplied nonce, and that hash checked on the server. 
The client machine should also be checked before checking the password. If the IP isn't static, it can be done with certificates.

The user-entered password shouldn't be used as anything other than a password, not as a key (use a KDF), not as an environment variable, nor stored any longer than it takes to hash it. Other secrets should be irreversibly derived from it and other values.

If you're not the developer and have been forced into this model by an application, then it seems like you're just looking for a local storage password manager like LastPass.

Comment: The deployment system is open source so I'll have to dig into the auth system and make some modifications so I can get a one-time use token verified by a certificate. Will that improve the security of the system?

Comment: Depends on the implementation, but if done right it's more secure. And keeps plaintext passwords from being sent and stored. What is the password normally stored in an environment variable for, BTW?

Comment: The deployment system manages Docker containers, one of which needs to make changes to the other Docker containers. Are there any big gotchas I need to be aware of? Any articles you would suggest? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Well - you are asking for trouble here with your current setup. Why do you have a deployment interface exposed to the web?

You need to add

1. IP whitelisting or host internally and connect into the network securely
2. 2FA using an authenticator - SMS is out these days
3. Store the salted hash not the password
4. Use PBKDF2 or bCrypt for the hashing. Look up current suggested iterations numbers and imimplementation